# How to change link background color in bootstrap navbar

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

i would like to know how can i change the background color when i hover over links in my bootstrap navigation bar

html:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-fixed-top">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
      <li><a href="#about">About me</a></li>
      <li><a href="#portfolio">Portfolio</a></li>
      <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>

  </div>
</nav>
```

css:

```
.navbar{
  background-color:#ff9900;
}
.navbar-nav > li > a{
  color:white;
  font-size:16px;
  font-weight:bold;
}

.navbar-nav > li > a:hover{
  color:blue;
  background-color:#ff9900;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a:focus {
  color:blue;
  background-color:#ff9900;
}
```

Comment: It seems that you already change. What's the problem?

Comment: Try to add !important like this `background-color:#ff9900 !important;`

Comment: the background color when i hover is still white for some reason heres my whole code: http://codepen.io/mheonyae/pen/ezNVeE

Comment: !important solved it now, thanks!

Comment: you can tick the green check to accept my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Change this

```
.navbar-nav > li > a:hover{
  color:blue;
  background-color:#ff9900;
}
```

To this:

```
.navbar-nav > li > a:hover{
  color:blue;
  background-color:#ff9900 !important;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Move the background-color to the links instead of the whole navbar
2. Add display: block to your links (if you want the links to take the whole width)
3. Change your desired background-color. In the example below `hotpink`

```css
.navbar{
}
.navbar-nav > li > a{
  color:white;
  font-size:16px;
  font-weight:bold;
  display: block;
  background-color:#ff9900;

}

.navbar-nav > li > a:hover{
  color:blue;
  background-color:hotpink;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a:focus {
  color:blue;
  background-color:#ff9900;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<nav class="navbar navbar-fixed-top">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
      <li><a href="#about">About me</a></li>
      <li><a href="#portfolio">Portfolio</a></li>
      <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>

  </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: doesnt seem to work,... if you wanna have a look at my whole code: http://codepen.io/mheonyae/pen/ezNVeE

Comment: @mheonyae - like this? http://codepen.io/MattDiMu/pen/yJNZXa I simply added the background-color to the a:hover selector